# mouse pointer changed to fingers

Tags: mouse, mouse-pointer

suddenly I get fingers and/or  pointer for mouse tip.  I tried the apps installed but no option to configure just for arrow.  Why did the fingers begin to appear?

Comment: Hello a good start is what version of Ubuntu are you using? What do you mean by tried the apps installed? More details please.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS  . The 'app' for mouse and touchpad.